# How do i replace a value in an object with another updated value in an object if the id matches?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Currently, I am storing genre in the reducer.

```
const genre = {
    "0": {
        "id": 1912,
        "title": "Fiction",
        "name": "Greg"
    },
    "1": {
        "id": 1957,
        "title": "Non-Fiction",
        "name": "John"
    },
    "2": {
        "id": 1958,
        "title": "Literature",
        "name": "James"
    },
}
```

How do i check if the **id in updatedGenre** matches the **id in genre**, then i would update the **title or name** in genre with the updated **title or name** based on the id.

```
const updatedGenre = {
    "id": 1958,
    "title": "Literature & Poems",
    "name": "Leo"
}
```

Sample Output: (Example id: 1958)

```
const genre = {
    "0": {
        "id": 1912,
        "title": "Fiction",
        "name": "Greg"
    },
    "1": {
        "id": 1957,
        "title": "Non-Fiction",
        "name": "John"
    },
    "2": {
        "id": 1958,
        "title": "Literature & Poems",
        "name": "Leo"
    },
}
```

Comment: Hint: use the map or filter method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: map and filter is for array

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to accomplish this with an iteration through your object. See below:

```
for (const key in genre) {
   if (genre[key]["id"] === updatedGenre["id"]) { 
      genre[key]["title"] = updatedGenre["title"] 
   }
}
```

Let me know if it works, best of luck!